# Need to understand the technique used in the artwork of sites like Slack, Hioscar, Avocode, etc

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, technique

So there is this sort of a pastel/raster artwork used in some sites that I want to learn to make and possibly replicate it. Please help my identify this these techniques

**Eg1:The pastel/paint marks on Slack** [image: The pastel/paint marks on Slack]

**Eg2:The patterns used on Avocode**[image: The patterns used on Avocodee]

**Eg3:Pastel images on Hioscar**[image: Pastel images on Hioscar]

Comment: Please limit your questions to one per, well, question. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent I clubbed seemingly similar techniques and their examples. Apologies if it is not so

Comment: These look like vector graphics with a raster pattern applied as a texture. I can clearly see a repeating raster pattern on [this one here](https://imgur.com/a/toNlUOb) which looks like a scan from something drawn on paper with a felt tip pen. What have you tried?

Comment: Thing is that, right now, there is no right answer to this question. An answerer could attempt to answer all three questions; be absolutely right about the first one but completely off the mark about the second and third. Would you upvote their answer? Downvote it? Mark it as correct and signal to new answerers 'this question has been handled, you can move on'? The Stack Exchange model is very, very bad at handling multi-part questions.

Comment: @BillyKerr I tried searching for 'pastel brushes for photoshop' but given what you're saying that clearly won't give the right result.

Comment: @Vincent Ah. fair point. I'll try and keep that in mind while asking a question from now on. For this one even if a technique can get me close enough to one of them, thats satisfactory for me

I have asked a similar question before with multiple examples. There I chose the answer with the most efficient technique and upvoted the other correct answers

Comment: There are a variety of techniques which could work, including the use of textured brushes.  Also, there is no way to know how these were created for certain. They could have been drawn in Illustrator, Photoshop, or other software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User Billy Kerr has already said the essentials and there's seemingly popped up an answer, too. Here's a practical way to create the textured colors:

Have a desaturated photo of an everyday material texture. Here's 3 different.

[image]

Insert 2 layers over the texture layer:

1. A curves or levels adjustment layer to get the wanted contrast; here the contrast is reduced
2. A layer with the wanted color, the blending mode Color is good for this purpose

[image]

Find good combination of the opacity of the color layer and the contrast of the texture layer. All adjustments are non-destructive.

Here's a screenshot of the curves adjustment. Note: the switch "only the next layer" is ON.

[image]

You can flatten the result or export as PNG or use it as is in Photoshop when you make the drawings.

I would draw the images in Illustrator or Inkscape and use exported colored texture images there with clipping masks. An advanced Inkscape or Illustrator user can easily apply layer blending modes also there, it's not at all a must to make ready to use colored images in Photoshop at first.

As user Daniello wrote, many blending modes work for this. You can colorize a texture or as well you can modulate the brightness of a solid color.

An example:

[image]

1. A texture image is imported to Illustrator
2. A colored rectangle is drawn and lowered under the texture
3. The rectangles are aligned and the texture image has got blending mode Luminosity, the opacity is reduced - this happens in the Transparency panel.
4. The rectangles are grouped to keep them together. A random closed shape is drawn on the top
5. The group and the new shape are selected, a clipping mask is made. For it goto Object > Clipping mask > Make.

The mask shape vanishes. If you need it, for example to get the stroke, have a copy. NOTE: You can allways release the clipping mask if you want to edit it.

Answer (score 6):

**Shapes**

It can be done in different ways, but the basics in all of them is:

- A texture
- A color overlay

[image: textured shapes]

[image: oranges]

**Strokes**

- Brush effects like watercolor brushes

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Danielillo
One question: With the color overlay are we applying any color mode (eg, multiply, overlay, etc.) or simply playing with opacities?

Comment: Both, opacity and Hard Light or Multiply, but this always depends on the used color and the texture intensity. The best it is adjusting the texture with levels to get the result you want and then decide the color blend and the opacity.